# Id tag inside a HTML5 code

Tags: html

I wounder if this is a correct code

```
<article>
   <section></section>
   <section id="section2"></section>
</article>

<article id="article2">
   <section></section>
   <section id="section2"></section>
</article>
```

So my questien is can I use the id tag inside of a new html5 code ?

Comment: why not, it should work.

Comment: New html5 tags are just the same as the rest of the tags.

Comment: Remember the section tag is not for use as a general container element: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-section-element. How to use the ID attribute in HTML5: http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/elements.html#the-id-attribute

Answer (score 3):

`id` is an attribute, not a tag. It can be used on *any* element. So yes, the code you posted is syntactically valid. However, **IDs must be unique**. So the code you posted is invalid because you re-use the ID `section2`.

As a suggestion, this can be answers in a much easier way than through Stack Overflow: Simply use the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/) - it will complain if you feed it with invalid HTML.

Comment: If you get rid of the duplicate ID then yes.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm late to the party but this question needs some additional clarification, I will also answer it of course.

**Clarification:**

HTML is NOT code, is **markup**. CSS and JavaScript are code. CSS is also known as a "Style Sheet Language".

**Answer:**

No different answer than what ThiefMaster said: "id" is not a tag, is an attribute.

In other words, if "id" was a tag it would look like this: `<id>`, and that does not exist, not even in HTML5. I wouldn't expect the W3C to come up with a tag like that one, but, never say never... :p

Check this post in CSS-Tricks.com about [The Difference Between ID And Class](http://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-id-and-class/).